# How to keep a up-to-date visible folder in GIT?

Tags: git, repository, msysgit

Right, after much struggle I finally managed to get a sort of shared folder among my *all* workmates where we can make a common `git` repo.

Googlin' on how to make that work, apparently the only thing I need is to set a magic flag `git config --bool core.bare true` and everyone is able to happily `push` and `pull` having set the remote as `file:///z/path/to/that/folder/`.

Briliant. But I want more.

There are lots of people who will have access to our files, but do not *git* then, if you know what I mean :)

Now what I noticed is that after setting the repo as `bare` the working tree is not updated anymore (well... I guess that's exactly the point of setting it `bare`). What I wish though, is that the working tree always reflected the HEAD of the master branch.

Even further, we have actually worked the permissions in a way that the "gitless" people won't be able to edit the working tree (provided that we manage to make it work the way described), but it would be great if any changes in the master:HEAD instantly overwrote whatever was changed in the working tree. i.e. do not bother generating conflicts and merges.

Are there any other flags that would make my gits come true? :)

thanks!

f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave the working directory of the master repo alone, and set up a non-bare repository to host the public working directory.

You want to look at git help hooks, and set up a post-merge hook in the master repo to tell the public working directory repository to pull changes.

Comment: okay. nice suggestion.. I used the ``post-receive`` hook, tried with relative paths and wrote a wrapper (publicpull.sh): ``cd ../../../public; git pull``. In the hook itself there's only the line: ``. ./publicpull.sh``.. But it doesn't work. Did I miss anything obvious?

Comment: Fina managed, the trick was to unset a couple variables: ``unset GIT_WORK_TREE ; unset GIT_DIR``. Thanks!